# awk how to print from column 4 to the end of line when last column contains a sentence

Tags: awk

If I have file fileA.txt containing lines like this:

```
Toyota 2017 Corola Good condition
Honda 2013 Civic Flat back right tire
Jeep 2017 Wrangler Roof is leaking and oil needs change
```

I would like to print only column 2 and 3 but column 3 contains sentence with spaces.  I would like my output to look like

```
2017 Corola Good condition
2013 Civic Flat back right tire
2017 Wrangler Roof is leaking and oil needs change
```

But I cannot make the last column print full sentence.  I get only last word like:

```
awk '{print $2,$NF}' fileA.txt
```

This outputs

```
2017 condition
2013 tire
2017 change
```

I know why this is happening.  It is because awk treats spaces as column separators and NF returns simply only last column for each line which is last word.

How do I get desired output using awk?

Comment: Possible [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info). Awk may not be the appropriate tool. More likely is the structure of the data should probably be changed to JSON or CSV.

Comment: See also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/561577/awk-print-from-nth-column-to-last

Comment: Are you allowed to change how data is stored or it was imposed at you? If first consider selecting character which does not appear in data for delimiting purpose, base on your sample date you might use TAB (`\t`) for that purpose.

Comment: no, I cannot change, it is just spaces, not tabs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would harness GNU `AWK` following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
Toyota 2017 Corola Good condition
Honda 2013 Civic Flat back right tire
Jeep 2017 Wrangler Roof is leaking and oil needs change
```

then

```
awk '{$1="";print substr($0,2)}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
2017 Corola Good condition
2013 Civic Flat back right tire
2017 Wrangler Roof is leaking and oil needs change
```

Explanation: I clear 1st field (`$1`) by setting its' value to empty string then `print` rest starting at 2nd character using [`substr` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) in order to remove leading space.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)*

Comment: A nice approach. Not applicable here, but if the record contains any additional whitespace, etc. in fields 2 - NF, assignment to the 1st field will cause `awk` to recalculate the fields trimming any additional whitespace. That's not a critique of your answer, you got my vote, but something to be aware of for others.

Comment: @Daweo Thank you but what if I had another column in the middle, say between year and comment column that I want to exclude?  How would I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Only downside to assigning an empty-string to field-1 is that it will cause a recalculation of the fields removing any additional whitespace from the original record. You can preserve the original record format (which may/may not be required) by using either `sub()` or `match` and then `substr()` with `RSTART` (filled by `match() containing the position of the start of the 2nd field).

For example:

```bash
$ awk '{sub ($1 FS, "", $0)}1' file
```

(substitute the empty-string for the field-1 and a field-separator)

or

```bash
$ awk '{match ($0,$2); print substr($0,RSTART)}' file
```

(use `match()` to obtain the start of field-2 and print with `substr()`)

**Example Use/Output**

With your sample data in `file` you would receive the following:

```
$ awk '{sub ($1 FS, "", $0)}1' file
2017 Corola Good condition
2013 Civic Flat back right tire
2017 Wrangler Roof is leaking and oil needs change
```

and

```
$ awk '{match ($0,$2); print substr($0,RSTART)}' file
2017 Corola Good condition
2013 Civic Flat back right tire
2017 Wrangler Roof is leaking and oil needs change
```

See [GNU Awk User's Guide - String Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html#String-Functions) for detailed usage of `sub()`, `match()` and `substr()`. (and note the difference in parameter order for `match()` compared with `sub()`, `gsub()`, etc..) Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: It won't be a problem with the OPs data but in general `match ($0,$2)` could fail if $2 was equal to or a substring of $1, or if $2 contained regexp metachars.

Comment: Good catch Ed. I breezed right past both of those cases with `match()`. Another example of there being no replacement for experience.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cut -d' ' -f2- file
2017 Corola Good condition
2013 Civic Flat back right tire
2017 Wrangler Roof is leaking and oil needs change

$ sed 's/[^ ]* //' file
2017 Corola Good condition
2013 Civic Flat back right tire
2017 Wrangler Roof is leaking and oil needs change

$ awk '{sub(/[^ ]* /,"")} 1' file
2017 Corola Good condition
2013 Civic Flat back right tire
2017 Wrangler Roof is leaking and oil needs change

$ awk 'match($0," "){$0=substr($0,RSTART+1)} 1' file
2017 Corola Good condition
2013 Civic Flat back right tire
2017 Wrangler Roof is leaking and oil needs change
```

Any of the above will work no matter which values are in $1 or $2 or anywhere else in the input.

If you wanted to separate each line into 4 fields you could do this with GNU awk for the 3rd arg to `match()` and `\S`:

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' '
    match($0,/(\S+) (\S+) (\S+) (.*)/,a) {
        print a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4]
    }
' file
Toyota  2017    Corola  Good condition
Honda   2013    Civic   Flat back right tire
Jeep    2017    Wrangler        Roof is leaking and oil needs change
```

and then you can, of course, print whichever fields you like.

Comment: Here another one  `grep -Po ' \K.*' file`